# The output is mot coming as expected and the values are getting returned as none

Tags: python, object

```
class Dog:
  def  bark (self ):
        print("The dogo is barking")
        return

  def yolo (self):
      print ("Munni badnam")
      return
  
d= Dog()
print(d.bark())
print(d.yolo())
```

This is my code

and this is my output -

```
The dogo is barking
None
Munni badnam
None
```

Comment: Yes.  What did you expect?  Your functions are returning `None`.  My GUESS is that you shouldn't have the functions do any printing.  Just `def bark(self):` / `return "The dogo is barking"`.  Let the caller decide what to DO with the string.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you expect.

```
class Dog:
  def  bark (self ):
      return "The dogo is barking"

  def yolo (self):
      return "Munni badnam"
  
d= Dog()
print(d.bark())
print(d.yolo())
```

As a very general rule, a function like that should not have side effects (like printing stuff).  Just let the function return its value, and allow the caller to decide what to DO with the value.

Comment: Okay , got it.. i removed the print statements and just called the function. I am getting the desired output but I am still not understanding why it returns none when I add the print statement? Can someone explain me that?

Comment: Yes.  Because you wrote `return`.  That specifically returns nothing -- it's the same as `return None`.  I'm not sure what you expected it to return. `print` is just a function.  It has no effect on the program.

Comment: Oh okay , got it , I even tried doing nested functions it gave me the similar output , but it clears my query , thanks again :)